# Checkbox to display more options

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8 to create a search form and would like the user to be able to check a box if they want the advanced search options to appear.

Here is what I have so far:

In my javascript file:

```
function showDiv(advancedVal)
{  
  if(advancedVal == '') {
    $('moreOptions').style.display = "";
  } else {
    $('moreOptions').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

In my CF file:

```
<input name="advanced" type="checkbox" value="" id="advanced" onclick="showDiv('');">


<div id="moreOptions" style="display:none;" class="moreOptions">
<table>
drop down boxes
</table>
</div>
```

The checkbox is in a different table, does this matter?

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using jQuery, your code should be:

```
function showDiv(advancedVal)
{  
  if(advancedVal) {
    document.getElementById('moreOptions').style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('moreOptions').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and

```
<input name="advanced" type="checkbox" value="" id="advanced" onchange="showDiv(this.checked)">
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XN8aK/1/

Comment: This works but for some reason when I uncheck the box again, the advanced options still appear.

Comment: Yes, that was because your checkbox has an empty value. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jQuery? Then it should be:

`$('moreOptions').style.display = ""` should be `$('#moreOptions').show()`

or

`$('moreOptions')[0].style.display = ""`

**UPD**

I guess this is what you want:

```
function showDiv(obj) {
    var more = document.getElementById('moreOptions');
    more.style.display = obj.checked ? "" : "none";
}​
```

And change your markup:

```
<input name="advanced" type="checkbox" value="" id="advanced" onchange="showDiv(this)">
```

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Kexbu/2/

Comment: Maybe he is using Mootools, question should specify.

Comment: I don't think I'm using jQuery, just Javascript (noob). Similar functions next to mine use the same syntax as the one I posted and work alright, I looked at them but can't seem to find where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change `$('moreOptions')` to `$('#moreOptions')`